# Getting unauthorized exception on reading file at onfileactivated method

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I was trying to copy PDF files when user selects the file from any where by associating the file type with my application.

unfortunately i get unauthorized exception when try to copy the file

```
  async  protected override void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs e)
    {//IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem>


        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {

            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new Frame();

            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage)))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }
        }

        StorageFolder magazinefolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("pdffolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        IAsyncAction asyncAction = Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool.RunAsync(
(workItem) =>
{




    foreach (IStorageItem tm in e.Files)
    {

        File.Copy(tm.Path, magazinefolder.Path);

    }


    //   this.loadlibrary();






});

        var p = rootFrame.Content as MainPage;
        // p.AddFileCall(e.Files);

        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();

    }
```

Comment: Assuming that your `tm` is a StorageFile, have you tried to do `tm.CopyAsync(magazinefolder);`?

Comment: yes but the same error

Comment: And when you don't redirect the work to ThreadPool - just run `await (e.Files.FirstOrDefault() as StorageFile).CopyAsync(magazineFolder);` do you also get an exception? Have you debuged and checked if you get a valid StorageFile? Is it possible you can share a sample project?

Answer (score 0):

rather than taking the files as IstorageItem we can directly get it as StorageFile which will solve the problem

```
 async public void AddFileCall(Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.FileActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        StorageFolder magazinefolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync(Constants.MagFolder, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        foreach (StorageFile file in e.Files)
        {
            await file.CopyAsync(magazinefolder,file.Name,NameCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        }

        MessageDialog Sucess = new MessageDialog("File Imported", "Thank You");
        await Sucess.ShowAsync();
        this.loadlibrary();
    }
```